# Filtering list of beans with expression

Tags: freemarker

I have a list of beans and I would like to get a sub list matching a criteria on one or several properties with an expression as below:

```
${data[propertyName=='my value']}
```

data is a list of beans that have a property called propertyName.

Is such approach possible? If not, what is the best approach to do that.

Thanks very much for your answers.
Thierry

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could write a FTL function which selects the list items that match your criteria and collect them in a new sequence via sequence concatenation. Your filter function can be very simple or very sophisticated, it depends on your actual use case. Here is an example how it might work:

```
<#function filter things name value>
    <#local result = []>
    <#list things as thing>
        <#if thing[name] == value>
            <#local result = result + [thing]>
        </#if>
    </#list>
    <#return result>
</#function>

<#-- some test data -->
<#assign data = [ {"propertyName":"my value",    "foo":150},
                  {"propertyName":"other value", "foo":250},
                  {"propertyName":"my value",    "foo":120}] >

<#assign filteredData = filter(data, "propertyName", "my value") >

<#list filteredData as item>
    ${item.foo}
</#list>
```

But keep into account that using sequence concatenation might be "suboptimal" for your performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by creating your own `filter` [method variable](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_datamodel_method.html) and exposing it to the template.  Then it would just be a matter of calling it with the list of beans and property value you want to filter on:

```
<#assign filteredData = filter(data, "my value") />
<#list filteredData as item>
    // do something fancy
</#list>
```